# EntityFramework 6 AsNoTracking and Projections

Tags: entity-framework-6

Given the following codes:

A.

```
using (var context = new testEntities())
{
    context.tblAuthors.Select(p => new
    {
        Author_name = p.Author_name,
        Id = p.Id,
        country = p.country,
        tblBooks = p.tblBooks.Select(z => new
        {
            Id = z.Id,
            Auhthor_id = z.Auhthor_id,
            Edition = z.Edition,
            Price = z.Price
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();

}
```

B.

```
using (var context = new testEntities())
{   
    context.tblAuthors.Include(p => p.tblBooks).AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

I ran both on a separate loop of a 100 iterations. The first code (A) gives me an average of 157ms execution time. The second code (B) gives me an average of 673ms execution time.

**My questions are:**

1 - Why does Entity Framework have this difference? I thought AsNoTracking() was supposed to perform the same as a Projection since the Context is not tracking the entities in both cases.

2 - If I want to get maximum performance should I be using projections for all read-only operations instead of AsNoTracking()?

**Update 1:** The amount of data that is being retrieved is the same. I am using all the available fields on the table. The query that is being generated by Entity Framework is the same for both codes.

Comment: The first query doesn't track anything either, *and* collects less data.

Comment: That's why I believe they should be the same. They are collecting the exact same amount of data as I am using all the fields available on both tables.

Comment: Then it's probably relationship fixup that takes the time. Even with `AsNoTracking` EF applies relationship fixup to the collected object graph. Additionally, the second query may materialize proxy objects, which may cause a notable difference.

Comment: I belive`tblBooks = p.tblBooks.Select(` this line will cause the tblBooks collection to be lazy loaded for each of the results in tblAuthors. Try changing it to `tblBooks = p.tblBooks.AsQueryable().Select(`.